# Google single-sign-on solution

Tags: single-sign-on, claims-based-identity, federated-identity, federation

Google has a funky solution for delivering SSO across all its sites. It seems to manage multiple accounts really well, allows for account linkage, allows the user to select from multiple accounts when trying to access a service etc. etc.

Is there any information about Google's exercise to deliver this SSO solution?

Also, I looked at their logon page and was wondering if anyone knows the purpose of the various parameters used in the URL on the logon screen?